# How to make REMOTE_USER private for the logged user in WSGI?

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I have developed a custom OAuth2 middleware in Python which sets the REMOTE_USER variable for the logged user, however I'm unable to make this variable private for visitors of the site.

https://bitbucket.org/tkadm30/django-hotsauce/src/fe96dc13edf65003e9453150a6fcd7059ab85461/lib/notmm/controllers/wsgi.pyx?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

In my main WSGI middleware (BaseController.init_request), I create the WSGI request object using the following code:

> ```
>    try:
>        _locals.environ = _locals.request.environ
>    except AttributeError:
>        _locals.environ.update(environ)
>
>    request = request_class(_locals.environ)
>
>    if request.environ != _locals.environ:
>        self.logger.debug("Updating environment")
>        request.environ.update(_locals.environ)
>
>    return request
> ```

Note:

- _locals is a threading.local object.
- The same code with gevent.local doesn't work.

Comment: thats not really how environmental variables work ...  I suspect there is a better way to do whatever it is you are actually trying to do... (IE why are you setting this variable?)

Comment: This is a standard WSGI app. I need to initialize a WSGI request object (a WebOb subclass) to return a WSGI response in BaseController.get_response. In Werkzeug, the same logic is assumed: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/wrappers/

Comment: thats great... but does not address the comment at all ... and thats still not how environmental variables work....

Comment: I'm now considering a decorator approach in order to protect a view with the OAuth authentication middleware: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40051499/how-to-handle-generator-code-inside-a-decorator

Comment: The OAuth authentification is using django-hotsauce-oauthclient api: https://bitbucket.org/tkadm30/django-hotsauce-oauthclient